# physics.stackexchange.com and the Physics proposal

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

There's an area51 [proposal for Physics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1908/physics) that will mature soon. There is also an existing SE 1.0 site on [physics.stachexchange.com](https://physics.stackexchange.com/), When the proposal mature, what will happen to the SE 1.0 site?

Comment: I don't think `[retag-request]` is a suitable tag here...

Comment: @KennyTM - sorry, I thought it was meant as a request for other people to retag this post, because I wasn't sure I tagged it properly.

Comment: @Dimension10 - there was a Stack Exchange 1.0 site for Physics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Physics 1.0 site expired several months ago and I do not know if the owner chose to export or publish their data, or if they have plans to continue the site.

Wherever possible, we are working with the Stack Exchange 1.0 sites that have created successful communities. That site has only 40 non-meta questions and does not receive very much traffic.

Comment: So I understand the answer is that it will get wiped when the proposal graduates.

Comment: I was the owner of the 1.0 site but having set it up and participated in the first few weeks I just left it, assuming it would pretty much run itself. Never had a single email relating to the site and didn't realise it had been replaced until I visited it again much later.