# Change the error site for previously existing SE-1.0 site that will probably be replaced by an Area 51 proposal

Tags: feature-request, support, stack-exchange, stackexchange-2.0

Or: What will happen to the questions at SE-1.0 physics.SO?
The site http://physics.stackexchange.com is no longer available, will its contents be migrated to the [Physics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1908/physics?referrer=Ho2q28uHijgN5QfMOt5KEg2) proposal when it gets started? In any case, the error message should be changed into some thing like

> The Q&A site physics.stackexchange.com will restart soon, please support it's relaunch: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1908/physics

Comment: Duplicate of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66988/physics-stackexchange-com-and-the-physics-proposal

Comment: @user133367: that does not treat the confusing error when now opening http://physics.stackexchange.com

Comment: It is the same for http://science.stackexchange.com/. It could map to http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4955/popular-natural-science

Comment: @PeterMortensen: True, although depending on their intentions it could also be [Natural Sciences and the Scientific Method](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/21647/natural-sciences?referrer=8PFgth2FBeGP1xPZSakPmQ2). Maybe that should even link to both